# Collation Ploblem

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to do a query whith an IN Clause, but having the following error:

> Mensagem 468, Nível 16, Estado 9, Linha 7
> Não foi possível resolver o conflito de agrupamento entre "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" e "SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS" na operação equal to.
>
> My Translation: Not possible to solve the collation conflict....

Both Databases Have Same Collation and are in the same sql server

[image: Properties of database SBOMarmovidro]

[image: Properties of database MarmovidroAUX]

following, the query:

```
declare
@inventario int

set
@inventario='3'
    
    insert into [MarmovidroAUX].[dbo].[Snap_Banco_Chapa]
select 
@inventario,
a.ItemCode as CodItem,
a.SysNumber as SYSNR_Lote,
a.DistNumber as CodLote,
a.Status,
a.AbsEntry as ABS_Lote,
b.ItemName as NomeItem,
a.U_Comp_A as Comprimento,
a.U_Larg_A as Largura,
a.U_Comp_B as Comprimento_B,
a.U_Larg_B as Largura_B,
a.U_Num_Bloco as Codigo_Bloco_Fabricante,
d.Name as Nome_Bloco_Fabricante,
a.U_Tipo_Mapa_Chapas as Tipo_de_Mapa,
a.U_Tipo_Chapa_Mapa as Posição_Chapa_no_Mapa,
a.U_Num_Chapa_Bloco as ID_Chapa_Bloco_Fabricante,
a.U_Lote_Pai as Lote_Pai,
a.U_Local_Chapa,
a.U_Chapa_L as Chapa_L,
c.WhsCode as Cod_Deposito,
e.AbsEntry as ABS_Posição,
e.BinCode as Cod_posição_deposito,
c.OnHandQty as Qtd_na_Posição

from

SBOMarmovidro.dbo.OBTN a 
left join SBOMarmovidro.dbo.OITM b on a.ItemCode=b.ItemCode
left join SBOMarmovidro.dbo.OBBQ c on a.AbsEntry=c.SnBMDAbs
left join SBOMarmovidro.[dbo].[@TAB_BLOCOS_CHAPAS] d on a.U_Num_Bloco=d.Code
left join SBOMarmovidro.dbo.OBIN e on c.BinAbs=e.AbsEntry

where

b.QryGroup1='Y' 
and b.frozenFor='N' 
--and c.WhsCode=06
and a.ItemCode in (select f.ItemCode from Tab_Filtros_Inventarios f where f.Inventario=@inventario)
```

Could you help me how to solve it?

Comment: Can you narrow down the cause of the error - I note you're not explicitely defining the columns to insert into - doing so would be a good start.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: The error will likely be in one of the `ON` clauses, where the 2 columns are different collations.

Comment: The database collation is just the default, columns can have their own collation, so you need to check the columns involved, and ideally correct the collation, but if not you can change the "cast" the collation of the offending column in the query itself.

Comment: check the two databases for any column of collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" : `select object_name(object_id) as tablename, name as colname, *
from sys.columns
where objectproperty(object_id, 'IsTable') = 1
and collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
`

Comment: Dale K and Lptr, the problem was the collation in column level. I did'n know it was possible. SOLVED! Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the collation names of the columns involved in the tables and see if there is any mismatch in collation.

For example, below query gives column level collation information of the tables involved in your query.

```sql
SELECT name, collation_name 
FROM sys.columns
WHERE OBJECT_ID IN (SELECT OBJECT_ID
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type = 'U'
AND name in ('OBTN','OITM','OBBQ','OBIN'))
```

Table variable columns will use the collation of the current database, unless specifically mentioned.[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c6a940fa-25a2-4e4e-b8c7-ce1ac672a6d1/table-variable-and-collation)

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't know it was possible to collate in column level. SOLVED!

Comment: @DiogoRoldão, you are welcome